# RxJava unsubscribe on Network close

Tags: java, networking, stream, rx-java, vert.x

i am currently trying to unsubscribe an observable, if the network request is closed, to not further stream the data.

My Observable is created with:

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.map { LocalDateTime.now() }.share()
```

So there are multiple subscribers. But I don't know how to unsubscribe if the network is closed.

I am currently stream the data with server-sent event with vert.x to the client like this:

```
flow.subscribe({
  response.write("the current time is $it")
}, ::println, {
  response.end()
})
```

If I cancel the request from the client, the observable will continue to "stream" the data.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unsubscribe subscriber by calling *dispose()*

```
Disposable disposable = flow.subscribe({
  response.write("the current time is $it")
}, ::println, {
  response.end()
})

disposable.dispose();
```

**UPDATED**: custom observable

```
val observable: Observable<LocalDateTime> = Observable.create { emitter ->
    val timer = Timer()
    timer.schedule(timerTask {
        if (emitter.isDisposed) {//<-- cancel emmitting items if disposed
            timer.cancel()
        } else {
            emitter.onNext(LocalDateTime.now())
        }
    }, 0, 1000)

}
disposable = observable.share().subscribe { t ->
    System.out.println(" Hello World! $t");
    disposable?.dispose()//<-- here calling dispose() causes observable to stop emitting items
}
```

Comment: this would call the dispose before the request is ended, didn't it?

Comment: you have to call dispose() when you want to cancel request and unsubscribe from observable

Comment: You can create custom observable and handle everyting yourself, i updated the answer

Comment: I've done a mistake. this worked: `response.closeHandler{ disposal.dispose()}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `takeUntil` operator with response `closeHandler`:

```
router.get("/test").handler(ctx -> {
    ctx.response().setChunked(true);
    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .share()
            .doFinally(() -> System.out.println("Disposed"))
            .takeUntil(Observable.create(e -> ctx.response().closeHandler(event -> e.onComplete())))
            .subscribe(l -> ctx.response().write(l.toString()));
});
```

Comment: vertx does not call the close handler when canceling the request from the client :-(